# How to fix '502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I develop a website that a user must upload an excel file and in background process a analyses that file and insert into database. But after a minute I receive this error in response

> '502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.'

Interesting things that when I check my database I see all data inserted correctly

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadExcel(int pid)
{
    var fileinput = Request.Form.Files[0];
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + fileinput.FileName);

    var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Files/" + fileName);

    using (var fileStrem = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await fileinput.CopyToAsync(fileStrem).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
        using (var dbase = new ApplicationDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext(new string[] { }))
        {
            using (var dbtrans = dbase.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

                    for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value.ToString() : "";
                        mymodel.field1 = worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value.ToString() : "";

                        dbase.SupportIndices.Add(mymodel);

                        await dbase.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    dbtrans.Commit();
                    return Json(new { state = "ok" });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    dbtrans.Rollback();
                    return Json(new { state = "err" });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you trigger the upload from client? Is it an Ajax request?

Comment: Yes. I use Ajax Request from Client

Comment: Can you please check if dB context timeout is configured ? If not it would use the default time which would not be enough in your case.

Comment: i use this code  ` public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
        {
            Database.SetCommandTimeout(150000);
        }`   but it's not work

Comment: I think something between client Ajax and database not work correctly. The client wait for response and database is working . that things when don't get answer from database sent status 502 to client . in other side the database finish it's job but there is no listener to tell it i'm finished . maybe it's happen

Comment: @Iman the server that your project hosted and server that serve requests from web is not same, maximum connectivity time between this two server I think is 60 seconds

Comment: @mostafa how can i change this time out ? and i don't understand different between two server that you say . i have only one server that hosted my website ( dotnet core ) and installed sql server 2017 . and only one client for request this website and upload an excel .

Answer (score 1):

Iman why you call `await dbase.SaveChangesAsync();` in each iteration? this take too much time to process finish.
there is two servers in your operation unit, first that uploaded webapp and another that just routes requests from web to local server inside organization, in this architecture security teams assign a timeout for connectivity of two server, check this connectivity duration first, and fix your code, you can use `SqlBulkCopy`, or just call `SaveChanges` one time.

Comment: i don't have two server . i have only one server that use for test and development this project. and i use await and async method because i see many sample and recommendation that when i want use an operation that contains I/O part it's better change function to async type.

Answer (score 1):

I have suggest you a one single thing which you make sure that it is must found in your IIS configuration, in short definitely your architecture is consist on old and new version of .net framework and may be core as well, the reason of this problem is to your included reference is unaware to respond in production env so go their IdentityPool of IIS right click and extend it time to 4 minutes first and monitor it in Event Viewer you easily pass through this error and also find which reference made you talkative here.